# Bat file manually runs but not running on schedule task

Tags: batch-file, process

I have a bat file that starts 11 bat files, but 3 of them doesn't start the other 8 runs without problems.

What can be the problem? Because if I start manually that bat files they run properly, but not in my bat file.

Thanks in advance

Edit The process Mcqmq950.exe needs to be run twice. This one start good but after 3 or 4 seconds change to Pause Status, the ENSPN001.exe start but suddenly dissapears

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Mcqmq950.exe" /FO CSV > search.log
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq ENSPN001.exe" /FO CSV > search.log

FINDSTR Mcqmq950.exe search.log > found.log
FINDSTR ENSPN001.exe search.log > found.log

FOR /F %%A IN (found.log) DO IF %%~zA EQU 0 GOTO end

start D:\MigrationPlan\MCI\PROCESOS\HOST-BAJADA.bat
start D:\MigrationPlan\MCG\PROCESOS\HOST-BAJADA.bat
start D:\MigrationPlant\Silabens\PROCESOS\enspn001_bajada.bat
:end
```

Hello again guys! I have found a solution, whis is:

```
D:
cd D:\MigrationPlan\MCI\PROCESOS

tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Mcgmq400.exe" /FO CSV > search.log

FINDSTR Mcgmq400.exe search.log > found.log

FOR /F %%A IN (found.log) DO IF %%~zA EQU 0 GOTO end

start D:\MigrationPlan\MCI\PROCESOS\MCIMQ400_MCI_MCG.bat
```

You need to specify the path where the file is before start operating with him

Too many thanks to all of you for your help.

Comment: Note that it's much more likely that we can point out your problem *if you include the code*. This question is more akin to »Hey guys, I have a problem. Which one of you can guess what it is?«

Comment: Place same logging in batch files just to be sure. Maybe they start, but doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @Sir_Kant: You are missing concatenation in your 2nd and fourth lines of codes. Replace `>` with `>>`. BTW, your test in FOR only guarantees **one** of the process is here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to use `call` for running the child batch files?

Comment: I use start instead of call, because the child batch files runs files .exe

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is being started by `task scheduler`.  Your 3 failing bat file don't have sufficient permissions with just the `system account permissions`.

Show us the failing batch files if you can't figure it out.